# How to return COUNT of function1's results in function2

Tags: postgresql, function, syntax-error

I have a function, let's call it `get_pants`, which returns the following in `psql`:

```
select * from get_pants ('calvin klein');
 size | length | color | type | price | discount | inventory | creation_timestamp 
-----+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+--------------------
(0 rows)
```

I can count the results of `get_pants` in `psql` also, like so

```
select count(*) from get_pants ('calvin klein');
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

But when I put the same code into a function, let's call it `foo`, like below, why do I get a syntax error

```
create or replace function foo ()
returns bigint as $$
begin
    return
        select count(*) from get_pants ('calvin klein');
end
$$ language 'plpgsql';
syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 4: return select count(*) from get_pants ('calvin.kl...
               ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PL/pgSQL you need to first store the result in a variable:

```
create or replace function foo()
returns bigint 
as $$
declare
  l_count bigint;
begin
  select count(*) 
    into l_result 
  from get_pants ('calvin klein');
  return l_result;
end
$$ 
language plpgsql
stable;
```

However you don't need PL/pgSQL for this:

```
create or replace function foo()
  returns bigint 
as $$
  select count(*) 
  from get_pants ('calvin klein');
$$ 
language sql
stable;
```

Note that the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. The syntax is deprecated and might not be accepted in a future version.

Comment: Is it advisable to switch between PL/pgSQL and SQL in the same database? I have many functions and most of them are written in PL/pgSQL

Comment: Wrapping a simple query into a SQL function is more efficient than PL/pgSQL especially if they can be [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_conditions_for_scalar_functions). There is nothing wrong with having some functions implemented in SQL and others in PL/pgSQL if you need procedural code.

Comment: Also, I think you're missing a return statement in the PL/pgSQL example